# any good alternative to Iconv library for encoding conversion?

Tags: encoding, iconv, big5

i was using Iconv library on Ruby to convert encoding from UTF-8 to UTF-32, UTF-16 etc and it was quite good.

However, I do see an issue when converting from Big5 to UTF-8 -- an exception is thrown for invalid sequence...

and the problem goes away when it is converting from CP950 to UTF-8, of which CP950 is essentially Big5...

so I wonder if there is another good alternative besides using Iconv?  Or is the CP950 a better version of Big5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although Big5 and CP950 are almost the same there are differences. On the Unicode website there are reference files for converting different encodings to Unicode, you will see that [Big5](http://www.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/OBSOLETE/EASTASIA/OTHER/BIG5.TXT) and [CP950](http://www.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/WINDOWS/CP950.TXT) are different. My experience of Iconv has been good - I suspect its behavior may be correct.

Some of the characters found in CP950 but not Big5 have the hex values: `0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x0D, 0x0E, 0x0F, 0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16, 0x17, 0x18, 0x19, 0x1A, 0x1B, 0x1C, 0x1D, 0x1E, 0x1F, 0x20, 0x21, 0x22, 0x23, 0x24, 0x25, 0x26, 0x27, 0x28, 0x29, 0x2A, 0x2B, 0x2C, 0x2D, 0x2E, 0x2F, 0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x37, 0x38, 0x39, 0x3A, 0x3B, 0x3C, 0x3D, 0x3E, 0x3F, 0x40, 0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x44, 0x45, 0x46, 0x47, 0x48, 0x49, 0x4A, 0x4B, 0x4C, 0x4D, 0x4E, 0x4F, 0x50, 0x51, 0x52, 0x53, 0x54, 0x55, 0x56, 0x57, 0x58, 0x59, 0x5A, 0x5B, 0x5C, 0x5D, 0x5E, 0x5F, 0x60, 0x61, 0x62, 0x63, 0x64, 0x65, 0x66, 0x67, 0x68, 0x69, 0x6A, 0x6B, 0x6C, 0x6D, 0x6E, 0x6F, 0x70, 0x71, 0x72, 0x73, 0x74, 0x75, 0x76, 0x77, 0x78, 0x79, 0x7A, 0x7B, 0x7C, 0x7D, 0x7E, 0x7F, 0x80, 0x81, 0x82, 0x83, 0x84, 0x85, 0x86, 0x87, 0x88, 0x89, 0x8A, 0x8B, 0x8C, 0x8D, 0x8E, 0x8F, 0x90, 0x91, 0x92, 0x93, 0x94, 0x95, 0x96, 0x97, 0x98, 0x99, 0x9A, 0x9B, 0x9C, 0x9D, 0x9E, 0x9F, 0xA0, 0xA1, 0xA15A, 0xA1C3, 0xA1C5, 0xA1FE, 0xA240, 0xA3E1, 0xA2CC, 0xA2CE`. If any of your input contains these values, then the file is not valid Big5.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/), it's a library that does character conversions among other things.

On the other hand, the other answers suggest you might need to examine your encodings more carefully.

Answer (score 2):

There are many many big5 variants. CP950 is just one of them.
http://www.moztw.org/docs/big5/

For big5, I would suggest use "big5-2003", which is official updated version.